# ASP.NET Core antiforgery token that works over multiple tabs?

Tags: angular, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, .net-8.0, antiforgerytoken

I recently migrated our app to .NET 8 and I'm trying to get our previously working antiforgery tokens to work. Most of it is working fine.

However, whenever opening multiple browser tabs we start getting validation errors saying the anti forgery token is not valid. I found this blurb in the Microsoft documentation stating that the synchronizer pattern is going to invalidate the antiforgery token whenever you open a new tab. It then suggests considering alternative CSRF protection patterns if this poses an issue.

However, it does not demonstrate other patterns in the documentation!

It seems to me that users using multiple browser tabs is commonplace now, so what other patterns are there? In every case they show, you are essentially creating a token, sending it down to the JavaScript and sending it back up in requests... what other pattern is even possible with an antiforgery token? I don't get it.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/anti-request-forgery?view=aspnetcore-8.0#antiforgery-in-aspnet-core

[image]

Comment: when you open a new tab, a new token will be generated, can't you just use the new token for the requests made by that tab

Comment: Well yes, but, as the documentation states, only the most recently loaded tab contains a valid antiforgery token. Therefore, if they user opens multiple tabs they're going to get an error when going back to the first tab they opened and continuing work there.

Comment: I just tried opening multiple tabs of the same asp.net core app homepage, and running this `$.post('Data/CheckAntiForg', { "__RequestVerificationToken": $('[name="__RequestVerificationToken"]').val() }, function(res) { console.log(res); })`, it works in all tabs, regardless of order of running, and they all have different tokens

Comment: Great to know your one specific implementation is working, but obviously we are working in different environments, and I didn't invent this problem out of confusion. I have been down the rabbit hole of posts where several people are having this issue and then found that even Microsoft validated that this is a real issue, so your response there doesn't do anything for me.

Comment: do you have some specific configuration related to the antiforgery token (in Program.cs or Startup), or is it everything by default ?

Comment: https://github.com/dotnet/AspNetCore.Docs/issues/25564

Comment: No, I'm doing things default as far as I can tell. I did find that github post and I believe that's what prompted them to add the blurb I pasted above about multiple browser tabs. This github post seems to say they don't support being logged in as different users in different tabs but they blurb they added to the documentation does not mention that, so it seems they're saying multiple tabs can kill it even with the same user login.

Comment: In the same documentation is described a way to generate the token as a cookie and how to retrieve it using javascript. That should work on mutiple tabs, right?

Comment: No, I don't think so... the way the token is transmitted, stored, or sent back up doesn't make a difference because the new tab gets a new token value and that seems to invalidate the old token value. I don't see how the vehicle of transmission changes how the AntiForgery library issues it's token.

Comment: @TonyE Why?  Cookies are shared across tabs.  Speculating on a solution isn't going to help

Comment: I'm actually putting the token into a javascript variable so it's not shared across tabs. Cookies are sent automatically so it's not recommended: "If cookies are used to store authentication tokens and to authenticate API requests on the server, CSRF is a potential problem. If local storage is used to store the token, CSRF vulnerability might be mitigated because values from local storage aren't sent automatically to the server with every request. Using local storage to store the antiforgery token on the client and sending the token as a request header is a recommended approach."

Comment: For reference, usually the token comes down in a hidden form field...not shared between tabs. But hmm, I may be able to set it in a cookie or localStorage so it's shared and gets updated by each new tab that loads up, and then on each request, grab that value and put it in a header to be validated there instead. I'll look into that.

Answer (score -1):

After more searching, it seems the solution is not to use an AntiForgery token at all, and use a different pattern entirely. There are a few listed in the OWASP cheat sheet for CSRF, although only one other method is not frowned up. That method is the Signed Double Submit Cookie method as described here, which I will pursue.

https://cheatsheetseries.owasp.org/cheatsheets/Cross-Site_Request_Forgery_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet.html

> ALTERNATIVE: Using A Double-Submit Cookie Pattern¶ If maintaining the
> state for CSRF token on the server is problematic, you can use an
> alternative technique known as the Double Submit Cookie pattern. This
> technique is easy to implement and is stateless. There are different
> ways to implement this technique, where the naive pattern is the most
> commonly used variation.
>
> Signed Double-Submit Cookie (RECOMMENDED)¶ The most secure
> implementation of the Double Submit Cookie pattern is the Signed
> Double-Submit Cookie, which uses a secret key known only to the
> server. This ensures that an attacker cannot create and inject their
> own, known, CSRF token into the victim's authenticated session. The
> system's tokens should be secured by hashing or encrypting them.
>
> We strongly recommend that you use the Hash-based Message
> Authentication (HMAC) algorithm because it is less computationally
> intensive than encrypting and decrypting the cookie. You should also
> bind the CSRF token with the user's current session to even further
> enhance security.
>
> EMPLOYING HMAC CSRF TOKENS¶ To generate HMAC CSRF tokens (with a
> session-dependent user value), the system must have:
>
> A session-dependent value that changes with each login session. This
> value should only be valid for the entirety of the users authenticated
> session. Avoid using static values like the user's email or ID, as
> they are not secure (1 | 2 | 3). It's worth noting that updating the
> CSRF token too frequently, such as for each request, is a
> misconception that assumes it adds substantial security while actually
> harming the user experience (1). For example, you could choose one of
> the following session-dependent values: The server-side session ID
> (e.g. PHP or ASP.NET). A random value (e.g. UUID) within a JWT that
> changes every time a JWT is created. A secret cryptographic key Not to
> confuse with the random value from the naive implementation. This
> value is used to generate the HMAC hash. Ideally, store this key as an
> environment variable. A random value for anti-collision purposes.
> Generate a random value (preferably cryptographically random) to
> ensure that consecutive calls within the same second do not produce
> the same hash (1).